# A bug when using jemdoc+mathjax

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, gbk, jemdoc

I am using jemdoc+mathjax([http://www.mit.edu/~wsshin/jemdoc+mathjax.html](http://www.mit.edu/%7Ewsshin/jemdoc+mathjax.html))  to make my website. However, when I am compiling, I came with the following mistake.
If I want to simply compile `jemdoc.py home`, then everything goes ok.
However, when I want to compile with the defult mysite.conf as follows

```
jemdoc.py -c mysite.conf home
```

then it does not run and the here is the bug report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\homepage\jemdoc.py", line 1646, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\homepage\jemdoc.py", line 1642, in main
    procfile(f)
  File "C:\homepage\jemdoc.py", line 1390, in procfile
    out(f.outf, f.conf['bodystart'])
  File "C:\homepage\jemdoc.py", line 380, in out
    f.write(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u2630' in position 747: illegal multibyte sequence
```

My system is windows 10 and the language is Chinese. But in my home.jemdoc, there is no Chinese character. Also, compiling using either python 2 or python 3 has the above problem.

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\u2630` character is `☰` (U+2630,  *Trigram For Heaven*). I'd check its presence in `mysite.conf`…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks a lot! I found that here is a `☰` in the sentence `<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>`. After deleting this character, the program ran correctly and the resulting html seems no wrong. I hope this character has no effect in the original `mysite.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the character `☰` (U+2630,  *Trigram For Heaven*) with another one (a similar glyph), e.g. with `≡` (U+2261,  *Identical To*).

`'gbk'` codec then encodes this character as

```
'\u2261'.encode('gbk')    # b'\xa1\xd4'
```

Another *similar* glyphs `\u2506` or `\u2507`:

- `┆` (U+2506,  *Box Drawings Light Triple Dash Vertical*)
- `┇` (U+2507,  *Box Drawings Heavy Triple Dash Vertical*)

In Python:

```
'┆ ┇'.encode('gbk')       # b'\xa9\xaa \xa9\xab'
```